# How to store High or Low values (trading)

Tags: python, series, algorithmic-trading, trading

I would like to develop a code which add a Series to my DataFrame; the Series should store the lowest value of the Close until a new low is reached. When a new low is reached a new value should appear in the Series. The starting code is:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ticker = 'EURUSD=X'
df = yf.download(ticker, start='2020-1-1')

df['fixed_low'] = ...?
```

So, for example, if the most recent low of EURUSD is 1.1000, in the column 'fixed_low' that value should stay until a new low is reached (let's say 1.0999). Then, if the asset is still going down, the column should store new low values until a new low will last for some time, and so on. I hope I was clear. Thank you

Comment: Answered. If you meant something else, correct me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. It's interesting that you want to do this, but what is your **question** about it? Please read [ask]. Can you think of steps that could be taken in order to solve the problem? (How would you solve the problem by hand, with a real pencil and piece of paper? You should at least know *how you would* do it, for a toy example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np


ticker = 'EURUSD=X'
df = yf.download(ticker, start='2021-2-1', end= '2021-3-1')
minimum = np.min(df['Close'])#you saved the minimum
print('minimum', minimum)

df1 = yf.download(ticker, start='2021-3-2', end= '2022-5-1')
for i in df1['Close'].values:
    if i < minimum:
        minimum = i

print('update minimum', minimum)
```

Two dataframes are created. In the first we find the minimum, in the second we update the minimum value.

```
ticker = 'EURUSD=X'
df = yf.download(ticker, start='2020-1-1')

df['fixed_low'] = np.nan

low = np.inf
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if df.loc[df.index[i], 'Low'] < low:
        low = round(df.loc[df.index[i], 'Low'], 6)
    df.loc[df.index[i], 'fixed_low'] = low
```

Output df

```
                Open      High       Low  ...  Adj Close  Volume  fixed_low
Date                                      ...                              
2019-12-31  1.120448  1.124101  1.120072  ...   1.120230       0   1.120072
2020-01-01  1.122083  1.122838  1.115947  ...   1.122083       0   1.115947
2020-01-02  1.121894  1.122712  1.116682  ...   1.122083       0   1.115947
2020-01-03  1.117081  1.118068  1.112570  ...   1.117144       0   1.112570
2020-01-06  1.116246  1.120825  1.115810  ...   1.116196       0   1.112570
...              ...       ...       ...  ...        ...     ...        ...
2022-05-06  1.053974  1.059839  1.048537  ...   1.053974       0   1.047285
```

Before the loop, I set the value of the low variable to the largest.
If the current minimum is less than low, then an update occurs. df['fixed_low'] set all values to nan first.

Comment: Thanks for your help! First of all I'd prefer to maintain a single dataframe. Furthermore I'd like to store the minimum values in a dataframe's series if possible.

Comment: We need a starting point. Let's say we took the history, found the minimum and recorded it in the column. Next, we monitor the quotes and compare them with the minimum from the dataframe. If it is updated, then we overwrite it. Such an algorithm of actions?

Comment: You got it! That's how it should work. And all the minimum values we get should be stored in a Serie, let's say we call it 'fixed_lows'.

Comment: How deep should I turn to history? Simply, if you search a lot, there will be an absolute minimum for the entire history of about 20 years ago.

Comment: Let's start from 2020-1-1

Comment: Updated the response.